# Autofac best practice passing parameters

Tags: c#, autofac

I've not been using Autofac for long, and I was wondering which is the best way to register parameters:

- using Register() method, with lamba expression

  ```
  builder.Register(a => new SomeClass(config))
         .As<ISomeClass>();
  ```
- using RegisterType() method and WithParameter()

  ```
      builder.RegisterType<SomeClass>()
             .WithParameter(new NamedParameter("config", config))
             .As<ISomeClass>();
  ```

The second way looks nicer to me, but I guess it's pretty dangerous to use as the name of the parameter can change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the way which better suits your needs. If you don't need much flexibility then use the first approach. But as soon as `SomeClass` dependencies will grow, you might want to use more flexible approaches like `NamedParameter`.

One more option is using named component registrations like

```
builder.RegisterInstance(config).Named<Config>("DefaultConfig");
builder.Register((c, p) => new SomeClass(p.Named<Config>("DefaultConfig")))
       .As<ISomeClass>();
```

Read more about those the topic from [Resolve Parameters](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/ResolveParameters) documentation

In any case the best practice would be to cover all your registrations by unit tests as well to avoid unexpected results.